# How to add 2 objects of a class by overide __add__ method?

Tags: python

I cam accross this question and trying to find a solution of it but I am unable to.
Any help?Thanks

Comment: I would say RTFM, but the question seems to contain its answer : simply rewrite it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a really lame example...

```
class A(object):

   def __init__(self, value):
       self.value = value

   def __add__(self, other):
       return A(self.value + other.value)

a = A(1)
b = A(2)
c = a + b
print c.value  # 3
```

ultimately, this is pretty much how *all* the hook methods work so it would be advantageous to try to understand it.  You define the method on the class, whatever it returns is the result of the operation.  Another way to think of it is:

```
c = a + b
```

is the same thing as `c = type(a).__add__(a, b)`<sup>1</sup>

<sup><sup>1</sup>This isn't quite the whole story -- there is some really interesting (and important to know) stuff that you can do with `NotImplemented` and `__radd__`, etc.  But master this part first before moving on to that part ...</sup>